# Name resolution in an IPv6 network without a DNS server

Tags: ipv6, domain-name-system, wins

Background:

1. I have a network with Windows and Linux machines
2. The router doesn't support IPv6, but the computers have link-local addresses (fe80::/10), and I plan to buy an IPv6-capable router in the future
3. I'm currently learning about IPv6 and experimenting with it, so there is no immediate problem to solve (since IPv4 works), but I want to learn about it now so it doesn't bite me later
4. I do not want to run a DNS server (for various reasons, such as not having a machine running 100% of the time, and not wanting to use static addresses)
5. IPv4 name resolution works using NBNS/WINS broadcast (natively on windows machines and using Samba/nmblookup on Linux machines).
6. If, for some reason, name resolution doesn't work, I can always resort to IPv4 literals, as I can easily memorize the last byte of a 192.168.1.0/24 address.

Now, the problem is that NBNS/WINS doesn't work with IPv6, so there is no name resolution. I can ping literal IPv6 addresses (after back-and-forth read/type cycles and lots of eye-squinting to find a single digit error...), but that's about it. I cannot do any name resolution. And unlike with IPv4, literal IPv6 addresses are not practical to use.

#### tl;dr: What's the equivalent of NBNS/WINS broadcast for ad-hoc name resolution on IPv6 networks?

Comment: Please read the FAQ.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers My apologies, I forgot that home networks belong to SU. But on the other hand, I also administer a small network at work, and I'm experimenting with IPv6 in my home network so I apply it later at work (no harm done if I break my home network). I'll remove "home" from my question.

Comment: Oh, and if a moderator feels that the question is more suitable for SU, feel free to migrate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [multicast DNS](http://www.multicastdns.org/), which will provide you with `.local` domain names. This is implemented on Mac OS X, on Linux using [Avahi](http://avahi.org/), and on Windows using the [Bonjour Print Services](http://www.apple.com/support/downloads/bonjourforwindows.html).

If you have a pure Windows Vista or 7 environment, you might be better off using [Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/community/columns/cableguy/cg1106.mspx). You will need to make sure you [enable the Network Discovery service](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2008/04/01/how-to-benefit-from-link-local-multicast-name-resolution.aspx); it is pretty poorly documented as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, Avahi and Bonjour Print Services did the trick, although I have to add ".local" to hostnames for multicast DNS to work. I also noticed that the Windows machines are already doing LLMNR among themselves.

Comment: You could probably add `.local` as a default search suffix, although I have not tested this on Windows and can't confirm that it works.

Answer (score -1):

Name Resolution in IPv6 Networks does not work by itself.It depends on NetBios,WINS OR DNS servers.If for any reason the above mentioned services are not available, you cannot connect
a name server merely by its name. You should have IPv4 or IPV6 addresses of the machine

Comment: WINS is not supported on IPv6, per Microsoft.http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/11/11/ipv6-for-the-windows-administrator-how-name-resolution-works-in-a-dual-ipv4-ipv6-scenario.aspx